# Examples of monads

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, monads

Recently, as a final degree project, I have been studying basic category theory. My tutor is very experienced in monads and so I am studying them. I have been researching some curious examples (the Giry monad, the monad of Directed graphs, the powerset monad, monads that come from a free-forgetful scenario where you forget the additional structure, the monad that "kills" the torsion)...

But I am very curious to know where could I find monads in topology? Or in analysis? What are the strangest monads you know?

I have consulted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278338/examples-of-monads-and-their-algebras) but I knew most of them. I am looking for something less abstract. I know my professor told me that you could see the real numbers as a monad. Something like that.

Comment: Depending on your background, my answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199061/applications-of-monadicity-theorems) and also [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279525/relating-three-viewpoints-on-the-semidirect-product) could be of interest to you.

Comment: In topology, the ultrafilter monad (over $Set$) has very interesting algebras : they're precisely the compact Hausdorff spaces

Comment: I am with @Max. I am currently working on the ultrafilter monad, using the ultrafilter space defined by Salbany. It's quite interesting. You can even get construct its algebra using the retraction of the ultrafilter space.

Comment: "monads that come from a free-forgetful scenario" - if you generalize this to pairs of adjoint functors, then *every* monad can be expressed as a special case of this (either using the Eilenberg-Moore category, or the Kleisli category).

Comment: In algebraic geometry, the Godement functor that takes a sheaf to a certain flasque "extension" of that sheaf is a monad.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Every monad comes from a free-forgetful scenario, if you consider the Eilenber-Moore category as "extra structure".